# Three js: I wanted to achieve something shown in the image, How can i do it, I have tried BoxGeomatry and planeGeomatry also its not same

Tags: javascript, three.js

As you can see in the image i want multiple images on the each side of the cube, I have tried with the BoxGeomatry but am not getting the exact output, so can any one help on this ?

[image: cube]

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted an image of the results you are currently seeing.

Comment: Use a CanvasTexture, draw the images into the canvas. See [this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-canvas-textures.html)

Answer (score 1):

Following [this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-textures.html#six) you can learn how to get a different image on each face. Following [this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-canvas-textures.html) you can learn how to use a canvas for a texture.

So by combining those techniques you can put a CanvasTexture on each face and draw images into the canvas.

```js
'use strict';

/* global THREE */

const loader = new THREE.ImageLoader();
async function loadImage(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    loader.load(url, resolve, undefined, reject);
  });
}

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 5;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 2;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const boxWidth = 1;
  const boxHeight = 1;
  const boxDepth = 1;
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);

  const cubes = [];  // just an array we can use to rotate the cubes

  // load 6 images
  const images = [];
  [
    'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/flower-1.jpg',
    'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/flower-2.jpg',
    'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/flower-3.jpg',
    'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/flower-4.jpg',
    'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/flower-5.jpg',
    'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/flower-6.jpg',
  ].forEach(async (url, ndx) => {
    const image = await loadImage(url);
    images[ndx] = image;  
  });

  // create 6 canvas textures
  const canvasTextureInfos = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = 256;
    canvas.height = 256;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    const texture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvas);
    canvasTextureInfos.push({ctx, texture});
  }

  // put a differnet canvas texture on each face of the cube
  const materials = [
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: canvasTextureInfos[0].texture}),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: canvasTextureInfos[1].texture}),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: canvasTextureInfos[2].texture}),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: canvasTextureInfos[3].texture}),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: canvasTextureInfos[4].texture}),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: canvasTextureInfos[5].texture}),
  ];
  const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);
  scene.add(cube);
  cubes.push(cube);  // add to our list of cubes to rotate

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
    
    // draw a random image on a random face
    const imgNdx = rand(6);
    const img = images[imgNdx];
    // check if this image has loaded
    if (img) {
      const face = rand(6);
      const {ctx, texture} = canvasTextureInfos[face];
      const x = rand(3) * 256 / 3;
      const y = rand(3) * 256 / 3;
      const width = 256 / 3;
      const height = 256 / 3;
      ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height);
      texture.needsUpdate = true;
    }

    cubes.forEach((cube, ndx) => {
      const speed = .2 + ndx * .1;
      const rot = time * speed;
      cube.rotation.x = rot;
      cube.rotation.y = rot;
    });

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function rand(max) {
  return Math.random() * max | 0;
}

main();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#c {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r108/build/three.min.js"></script>
```